# SELECT ... GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

```
id  - a_id  -  a_type
---------------------------
1      9       Granny Smith
2      9       Pink Lady
---------------------------
3      3       Pink Lady 
4      3       Fuji 
5      3       Granny Smith
---------------------------
6      7       Pink Lady
7      7       Fuji 
8      7       Fuji
9      7       Granny Smith
```

Ok, assuming we have an Apple sql table like above;
my question, is possible to have a result like below, with one query?

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => a_id: 7
        [1] => Pink Lady: 1
        [2] => Granny Smith: 1
        [3] => Fuji: 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => a_id: 9
        [1] => Granny Smith: 1
        [2] => Pink Lady: 1
        [3] => 
    )
...
```

PS: my own query is this:

```
SELECT a_type , a_id , 
COUNT(a_type) AS tot 
FROM #apple 
GROUP by a_id , a_type 
HAVING tot > 0 
ORDER BY a_type DESC
```

but this doesn't do what I need, it produces more than one `a_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT a_id,a_type,COUNT(*) FROM Apple GROUP BY a_id, a_type

This will get you a list of distinct a_id and a_type tuples, but you will still have to parse the list to consolidate those of the same a_id into a single hash table.

Or, if you want to, in one step, aggregate all by a_id, do this

```
SELECT a_id,GROUP_CONCAT(type_count)
  FROM (SELECT a_id,a_type,CONCAT(a_type,",",COUNT(*)) as type_count
          FROM Apple GROUP BY a_id,a_type) as x
 GROUP BY a_id;
```

This will get you:

```
7    Pink Lady,1,Granny Smith,1,Fuji 2
9    Granny Smith,1,Pink Lady,1
```

Regarding my comment: if you have MySQL this is what you get

Creating the exact table you have, with the exact data, and run my query, I get the following.

```
mysql> SELECT a_id,GROUP_CONCAT(type_count) FROM (SELECT a_id,a_type,CONCAT(a_type,",",COUNT(*)) as type_count FROM Apple GROUP BY a_id,a_type) as x  GROUP BY a_id;

|    3 | Fuji,1,Granny Smith,1,Pink Lady,1 | 
|    7 | Fuji,2,Granny Smith,1,Pink Lady,1 | 
|    9 | Granny Smith,1,Pink Lady,1        |
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that GROUP_CONCAT may be MySQL specific.

Can't put code in comment, so see my edited answer.

Comment: Yeah, you are right! it worked fine , my mistake , sorry again! 
PS: i can't still vote but you know! +1 for you mate!

Comment: You can put code in comments with backticks, like `int i = 1;`

Answer (score 1):

You could create a list like that with a `group by`:

```
select a_id, a_type, count(*)
from AppleTable
group by a_id, a_type
```

Comment: Thank's Andomar, but i have used this one too on my own, but the result is like this: a_id = Pink Lady: 1 , a_id = Granny Smith: 2 and not the compact form i need!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table group by a_id
```

using group by statement you can group the data by one or more columns 
[GroupBy Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: sorry, Marcx but this do not COUNT how many "Apple Type" PER "a_id" and don't display ALL the "Apple Type" per "a_id"! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `distinct` and `group by` like this

```
select distinct(a_id), a_type, count(a_type) as total_types
from Apple
group by a_id, a_type;
```

That way, you're getting the Apple id and it's types as well as how many (id, type) results are there as a group.

Comment: thank's but this produce the same result of the one from Andomar! ;-(